# CPU affinity is not being limited by taskset

Tags: rust, affinity

I am using the taskset tool to set CPU affinity for my multithreaded Rust program which queries data from MongoDB:

```
taskset -c 16-31 cargo run
```

When I run this command, I find that the program will also run on other CPUs as observed from `htop`. What went wrong and how to I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide a program that reproduces this? As far as I understand it, CPU affinity should be inherited by all child processes, even from Cargo to the actual application.

Comment: Have you tried running your program directly instead of running it via Cargo? `taskset -c 16-31 target/...` (`cargo run` should print the path to the executable)